# Global variable not being updated globally

Tags: javascript, json, function, global-variables

I'm attempting to create a webpage to visualize a family tree using JSON. I'm using the `uploadJSON()` function to store the JSON data from a file in to the global variable `tree`, which seems to work until I try to access `tree` in another function. When I do `console.log(tree);` in `addToDropDown()` it shows up in the console as undefined. I've tried setting `tree` to a default value of `"Testing"` when it's initialized, which does not get overwritten when I call `uploadJSON()`.

```
let tree;
let dropDown;

window.onload = function() {

    // Upload JSON File
    document.getElementById( 'upload-button' ).onclick = function() { uploadJSON(); };

    // Get Dropdown
    dropDown = document.getElementById( 'family-memeber-select' );

}

function uploadJSON() {

    let files = document.getElementById( 'upload-file' ).files;
    if( files.length <= 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    let fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function( e ) {
        console.log( e );
        let result = JSON.parse( e.target.result );
        tree = result;
        console.log(tree); // This outputs the tree object from the JSON file as expected
    }

    fr.readAsText( files.item(0) );


    addToDropdown();
}


function addToDropdown()  {
    // Add all family members to a dropdown list

    console.log( tree );
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not wrapping the functions *inside* the load event?

Comment: `fr.onload` sets an event listener, then `addToDropdown()` function is being called so when it's called, `fr.onload` is not called yet, I don't know exactly how to solve it, but that's your problem

Comment: Maybe you can call `addToDropdown()` function in `fr.onload` event

Comment: @JoelHager its just how I've done it in the past, I've never had this issue before. Is there a cleaner solution than moving `addToDropdown()` inside of `fr.onload`?

Comment: @VaheYavrumian Thanks! it works perfectly now!

Comment: @ZacharyElkins I posted my comment as an answer, please mark it correct so other people could find their answers more easily

Answer (score 1):

`fr.onload` sets an event listener, then `addToDropdown()` function is being called so when it's called, `fr.onload` is not called yet, I think the best solution would be calling `addToDropdown()` function in `fr.onload` event, so the function will be called when the event is fired